# Route traffic from eth1(local network) to eth0(external network) where ubuntu is dhcp server

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp, connection

I have an ubuntu server which is configured to be DHCP server to give IP address to a cisco switch through eth1.

eth0(connected to the external network)
ip:10.106.24.182
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.106.24.1

eth1(connected to the switch to give ip address)
ip:192.168.168.2
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.168.1

The dhcp packets are going fine and the DHCP offer has the following details.
IP(for switch to use):192.168.168.4
netmask:255.255.255.0
gateway:192.168.168.1
tftp-server:10.106.16.20

i have enabled the ipv4 forwarding and the interfaces in /etc/network/interface file is also set to "INTERFACE=eth1".
But i am not able to ping the eth0 gateway or the tftp-server from the switch.
I am not even able to ping the gateway(192.168.168.1) of eth1 sometimes.
Also the internet connection through eth0 for my ubuntu machine keeps going down and i wont be able to access the internet on my ubuntu machine.
I have confirmed that it is not the network issue because my other devices and windows machine connect just fine.
Any help regarding the same will be much appreciated since i am new to UBUNTU and i have been trying this for a week now.

Comment: Edit your post with the output of 'sudo cat /etc/network/interface'